# Mysql: Extend one table structure with another table structure

Tags: mysql

Is there a way to extend/merge ones mysql table structure into another, while keeping the table data intact?

For example i have developed something on the local copy of the database and to transfer all database changes into production i have to copy all new columns etc into production afterwards.

Would be nice to see all the differences between databases and have some dump generated based on these differences.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

local_table

```
loc_id, loc_desc, loc_price
```

production_table

```
pro_id, pro_desc, pro_price
```

I want to insert data from *production_table* to *local_table* and if the *loc_id* is same as *pro_id* I want to ignore it. Thereby, I'm only inserting the new rows, without replacing/changing the data in *local_table*:

```
insert ignore into local_table(loc_id, loc_desc, loc_price)
select pro_id, pro_desc, pro_list_price\n
from production_table
join local_table
where loc_id != pro_id;
```